# Activity gets destroyed when Intent is called

Tags: android, android-intent

I am calling share intent inside an activity.

```
public void share() {
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey, download this app!");
        startActivity(shareIntent);
}
```

**Actual Behaviour:**

Share Intent is shown but current activity is destroyed and moved to the previous screen.

**Expected Behaviour:**

Want to show share intent on top of current activity only.

**Update:**

RCA: It's calling appInPauseState lifecycle when the intent is called and it's causing to move from there. Is there a way to differentiate not to execute when the intent is called?

Comment: posted lines wont make current `Activity` finish its runtime, your problem must be somewhere else (bug in runtime or in some other methods called with `share()`). also `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag is redundant

Comment: Yeah. It's calling `appInPauseState` lifecycle when the intent is called and it's causing to move from there. How can I differentiate not to execute when the intent is called?